# How to set default value in BehaviourSubject

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

Probably a noob question. How do I set a default value to a BehaviourSubject.

I have an enum with 2 different values

```
enum class WidgetState {
    HIDDEN,
    VISIBLE
}
```

And a behaviour subject which emits the states

```
val widgetStateEmitter: BehaviorSubject<WidgetState> = BehaviorSubject.create()
```

My emitter starts emitting when the view logic is written. However it's HIDDEN by default. How do I set the default value as WidgetState.HIDDEN to my emitter `widgetStateEmitter`?

Comment: [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html) has a decent documentation which includes: "This subject does not have a public constructor by design; a new empty instance of this BehaviorSubject can be created via the create() method and **a new non-empty instance can be created via createDefault(Object) (named as such to avoid overload resolution conflict with Observable.create that creates an Observable, not a BehaviorSubject).**"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a static [`BehaviorSubject.createDefault(T defaultValue)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html#createDefault-T-) factory method that allows to set the initial value.

The Javadoc for the `defaultValue` parameter says:

> **`defaultValue`** - the item that will be emitted first to any `Observer`
>   as long as the `BehaviorSubject` has not yet observed any items from
>   its source `Observable`

So you just have to create your `BehaviorSubject` as follows:

```
val widgetStateEmitter: BehaviorSubject<WidgetState> = 
        BehaviorSubject.createDefault(HIDDEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor or onCreate (or similar) just call `widgetStateEmitter.onNext(HIDDEN)`

Answer (score 1):

When Subscribing to this Subject you can use [Start with Operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/startwith.html)

```
widgetStateEmitter.startWith(HIDDEN)
//continue your chain
```

Comment: But then other subscribers won't get the default value

Comment: Yes, @MidasLefko. That is correct. each subscriber needs this operator.